# Rails: rendering link with remote: true doesn't fire AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a project in Rails 3, with a partial `_form_fields.html.erb` that is rendered to a page and contains a remote link:

```
<!-- a few form fields, then... -->
<%= link_to '+', new_my_controller_path, remote: true %>
```

This gets processed by a controller, and appends this same partial below itself.

The controller:

```
def new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

And the related `js.erb` file:

```
$('.field-wrapper').append("<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: 'form_fields', layout: false)) %>")
```

All pretty standard, and the link loaded with the page works as expected, rendering the fields.

However, and here is my problem, when clicking this link on the newly rendered content, it submits as a regular link, ignoring `remote: true`.

Does anyone know the solution to this? I can't be the first person to have faced this, though haven't been able to find a solution - duplicates happily accepted if anyone can find one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you included the standard JS libraries?
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
Without these the remote: true tags won't work

Comment: Yeah, that's all in place @Mark - the first request fires fine, it's the second that has a problem. Cheers though.

Comment: It's the same template being rendered @Mark - if I forgot it in the new one, I forgot it in the first. Which I didn't :)

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Comment: Have updated the question @JohanWentholt, Rails 3. Apologies, should have specified.

Comment: I don't think rails 3 uses event delegation, so when you add something to the DOM like this it won't have the event attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this after a little debugging.

Looking at the terminal output when clicking the link, I noticed sometimes it would attempt to submit via JS, quickly followed by HTML; others, it would appear just to submit via HTML.

This suggested a race occuring between the default behaviour and that resulting from using `remote: true`.

The solution was to call `e.preventDefault()` on the element's click handler:

```
$('.my-element').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); })
```

Not ideal, and I presume fixed in newer Rails versions, though provides a little closure here :)